# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 17

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got this error when i viewed my php code in my browser.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 17.

```
<?php
$host="host"; 
$username="username"; 
$password="password"; 
$db_name="db"; 
$tbl_name="users"; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$_SESSION[username]' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ( $row['perm'] == "admin" ) {
  echo "Admin<br />";
} else {
  echo "Welcome to my homepage!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Missing an `}` at the end.

Comment: At the end of line 17 or the end of the code?

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Indenting your code properly, or using a decent IDE would have identified the cause of this

Comment: @andrewcoder2014 You would see it if you used proper indentation.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit on this question. It added indentation, which was good, but also the missing closing brace, which was the whole reason that the question was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the end curly bracket for your while statement. You should also be using MySQLi or PDO instead of the old mysql functions. Here is a reference for the new functions which are will be supported in upcoming versions of PHP. I have found this to be a very handy tutorial & reference guide in the past.
http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

```
<?php
$host="host"; 
$username="username"; 
$password="password"; 
$db_name="db"; 
$tbl_name="users"; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$_SESSION[username]' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if ( $row['perm'] == "admin" ) {
        echo "Admin<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Welcome to my homepage!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When i ran the code i did not get the error but i just got a blank page.